# Quick way to count missing values in many variables

Tags: python, spss

I've created a small program to count the number of 'None' so missing values. But the issue is that it is very time consuming (around `6-7mn` for `1000` variables, and this is way too much because I am working on a lot bigger datasets).

So I am looking for an alternative, and maybe someone can help here. Here is my program:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss
vars=spss.GetVariableCount()

for i in range(vars):
    dataCursor=spss.Cursor([i])
    oneVar=dataCursor.fetchall()
    dataCursor.close()
    miss=str(oneVar)
    counter=miss.count('None')
    #print counter
print "done"
END PROGRAM.
```

I've also tried to replace:

```
counter=miss.count('None')
```

by

```
counter=miss.find('None')
```

but this is not changing anything. Is anyone able to help me here? I saw with google help this program:

```
begin program.
import spssdata
majors = []
for case in spssdata.Spssdata('mq1'):
    major = case[0]
    if major not in majors:
        majors.append(major)
print majors
end program.
```

but I am not able to make it run for all variables. Because when we have a `'None'` it will always be listed in the first position of that list, I thought it might help to find a solution.

If anyone has any idea, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPSS syntax `aggregate` command can do this easily:

```
aggregate ...... /nms1 to nms1000=nmiss(var1 to var1000).
```